# VS Code - Authorize An Org - Failing on SFDX command

Tags: vs-code, sfdx-plugin

I recently started getting an error when trying to authorize an org using the Salesforce extension in VS Code.

This is the error I am getting:

```
sfdx org:login:web --alias PackagingOrg --instance-url https://login.salesforce.com --set-default
'"C:\Users\james\AppData\Local\sfdx\client\bin\..\7.209.6-8ba3197\bin\sfdx.cmd"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.
```

This operation was working fine just a few weeks ago and the operation `SFDX: Deploy Source To Org` still works fine to deploy to the org I am currently authorized for.

I have checked the PATH environment variable and I see that `C:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\bin` is there and that path does have `sfdx.cmd`.

The path mentioned in the error only has node.exe so I understand why `sfdx.cmd` isn't found there but that path isn't even in the PATH environment variable.

I also checked all of the settings for the Salesforce extension pack in VS Code to see if that bad path is in the settings somewhere and it isn't.

I'm not sure what to do next.

Comment: Wish I had an answer for you, but I am having the same issue. I tried updating the CLI and all the usual stuff but still no luck. I hope you find a solution (if you haven't already). I am banginig my head against the wall trying to figure out the problem